# Intellij is not respecting the java code import formatter

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, formatter

I have a java code formatter xml file:

```
<code_scheme name="zhc" version="17">
  <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="120" />
  <option name="CLASS_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="1000" />
  <option name="NAMES_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="1000" />
  <option name="IMPORT_LAYOUT_TABLE">
    <value>
      <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="true" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="com" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="java" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <package name="javax" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="org" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
    </value>
  </option>
</code_scheme>
```

But when I choose Code->Optimize Imports after I imorted this formatter file under Preference->Code Style->Java, It just doesn't work as the sequence written above.

Does anybody happen to know what's the problem here?

Comment: Is this the entire file you've tried to import? You need to preserve the full structure of the tags, starting with the `code_scheme` tag on the top level; you can't just cut some XML ouf of the middle of an exported file and import it.

Comment: No, it's just a code segment here, I imported all file together.

Comment: I udpated the whole file here, would you mind have a look again?

Comment: Does anyone happen to know the answer?

Comment: Who knows the answer?